# Linear subspace property of Gaussian integrals

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

In this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tomU1q3AdY) at 19:32, the following method of reducing a multivariate integral is discussed:

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ be the parameter vector, $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$ be the $i$-th data vector, $y_i \in \{-1,1\}$, be the corresponding binary observation. Also let $\phi(\cdot)$ denote the logistic sigmoid function. We want to simplify the following integral (product of sigmoid and multivariate Gaussian terms)

\begin{align*}
z & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^p} \phi(y_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \theta)~ \mathcal{N}(\theta|\mu, \Sigma) d \theta \\
\end{align*}

This can be expressed as an expectation with respect to $\theta$:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta} [\phi(y_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \theta)]
$$

and since $u := y_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \theta$ is a sclar, we can write this as:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{u} [\phi(u)]
$$

which is a one-dimensional expectation. I understand that $u$ is Gaussian, but I do not understand why the distribution the expectation is taken with respect to can be changed like that

Comment: Nothing was changed.  $y_i\mathbf{x}_i^\prime \theta$ is simply a scaled version of the marginal of $\theta$ in the $y_i\mathbf{x}_i$ direction. It's a defining property of Normal distributions that all marginals themselves have (univariate) Normal distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer goes along these lines: Essentially it is Fubini and Substitution for multivariate integrals.

Let us assume that $d=2, \Sigma=\text{Id}$ and $\mu = 0$. Notice that the density takes the shape

$$\mathcal{N}(\Theta, \text{Id}, 0) = \text{const.}~ e^{-|\Theta|^2/2}$$

in this case. I will ignore the constant to keep the formulae simple. Take a rotation matrix

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) \\ \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) \end{pmatrix}$$

such that $y_i A^T x_i = (c,0)^T$ where $c \neq 0$. If we execute the substitution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) $\Theta \mapsto A\Theta$ then we get that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi(y_ix_i^T\Theta) \mathcal{N}(\Theta, \text{Id}, 0) d\Theta = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi(y_ix_i^TA\Theta) e^{-|A\Theta|^2/2} d\Theta$$

but notice that a vector $\Theta$ and its rotated variant $A\Theta$ have precisely the same length, i.e. $|A\Theta| = |\Theta|$ so that this simplifies to

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi((y_iAx_i)^T\Theta) e^{-|\Theta|^2/2} d\Theta = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi(c\Theta_1) e^{-\Theta_1^2/2} e^{-\Theta_2^2/2} d\Theta$$

At this point we use the Theorem of Fubini (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) which allows us to write the integral over the total domain $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $\Theta$ as an iterated integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(c\Theta_1) e^{-\Theta_1^2/2} e^{-\Theta_2^2/2} d\Theta_2 d\Theta_1 = \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\Theta_2^2/2} d\Theta_2 \right ) \cdot \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(c\Theta_1) e^{-\Theta_1^2/2}  d\Theta_1\right)$$

Now if we do not forget about the normalizing constant above and drag it along all the time then we have $(2\pi)^{-1}$ in front which we write as $\sqrt{2\pi}^{-1} \sqrt{2\pi}^{-1}$. The expression becomes

$$\left( \sqrt{2\pi}^{-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\Theta_2^2/2} d\Theta_2 \right ) \cdot \left( \sqrt{2\pi}^{-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(c\Theta_1) e^{-\Theta_1^2/2}  d\Theta_1\right)$$

The first integral vanishes (because it integrates to the constant $\sqrt{2\pi}$) and the second integral is what you wanted: an integral over the logistic function "in a univariate Gaussian expectation". If the amount of dimensions is more than $2$ then everything still works but gets a little messier. If $\Sigma$ is not the identity matrix and/or $\mu \neq 0$ then $\Sigma$ can be diagonalized unitarily (basic linear algebra) so you use some substitution $\Theta \mapsto U\Theta - \mu$ or so in advance in order to force the situation $\Sigma=\text{Id}$ and $\mu=0$ just as you do in the case of a univariate normal.

Comment: could you explain why you chose $A$ in that way? One of the main points of the question was to understand what distribution I should take the expectation with respect to. Under your approach we should have the expectation wrt marginal distribution of $\theta_1$

Comment: @dimebucker91: 1) I choose $A$ in that way because this allows me to "plit" the sigmoidal term into things that only have to do with $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ respectively in order to split the whole integral. This is in fact what the lecturer means by 'logistic functions on one axis': The logistic part is not really multivariate but depends only on a one dimensional thing and by rotating the situation in that way we make it explicitly 'visible'. 2) That is not a contradiction, in fact, it's the same thing: marginals of multivariate Gaussians are univariate Gaussians (see

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions)